# Will longer interval during NightLapse mode on GoPro hero4 increase battery life?

Tags: battery, timelapse, gopro

I'm using 10 sec exposure on hero4 silver
Usually with no interval
The battery runs off after about 2.5 hours

If I'll increase the interval time, will it give me longer shooting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In my testing, NO.** I used a 60-second interval (see video) and the battery lasted 136 minutes, and I have repeated this test a few times. Your best bet is to do what I did and buy the battery charger, which will charge a battery before the other one runs out. Then, during your interval at some point, change the battery and re-start the time-lapse. You can do that indefinitely.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6dHS7JMTFA

Comment: That's what I did. I bought two batteries at Aliexpress and they should arrive in about a month. Thanks for the answer. Buy the way I just finish NightLapse with 15 sec interval and 10 sec exposure, and it kept rolling for 170 minutes

Comment: Yeah there's a ton of variables. Don't expect good performance from knock-off batteries though.

Comment: Of course not. I also bought a skeleton with an open side door so I can charge the camera while shooting